# shell simulator issue in C "no such file or directory"

Tags: c, shell, compiler-errors, simulator

I've gotta do a shell simulator in C where some commands are mandatory, I'm placing the code here

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#define ARRAYMAX 512

char *entrada = NULL;
size_t linha_tam = 0;

int i = 0;
char* token;
char* array[ARRAYMAX];

void help(){
    printf("SHELL DESENVOLVIDA POR:\n ADERBAL NEVES CALMETO JÚNIOR\n GUILHERME DE CASTRO PAOLUCCI PAIVA\n");
    printf("PARA SAIR DIGITE q\n");
}

void tokens(void *ent){
    
    token = strtok(ent, "\n ");
    
    while(token != NULL){
        array[i++] = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, "\n ");
    }
    array[i] = NULL;
}

void exec(){
    int *a;
    int pid = fork();
    if(pid != 0){
        waitpid(-1, a, 0);
    }else{
        if(execvp(array[0], array) == -1){
            printf("%s", array[0]);
            perror("Comando inválido");
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    printf("Seja bem-vindo!\nDigite h para ajuda\n");
    while(1){
        printf(">");
        getline(&entrada, &linha_tam, stdin);
        if(strcmp(entrada, "\n") == 0){
            printf("Insira um comando\n");
            continue;
        }
        tokens(entrada);

        if(strcmp(array[0], "q") == 0){
            return 0;
        }else if(strcmp(array[0], "h") == 0){
            help();
            continue;
        }else{
            exec();
            printf("%s", array[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

the issue is, if I try to call "ls" right after starting the program, it works fine, but when I try to call "help" then "ls", the program crashes saying

```
ls: cannot access 'ls': no such file or directory
```

that's a error native from the lib, not written by me
I've tried to put some kinds of prints right on the "else" that comes first on the "ls" function but it's not printed, so, I've got no idea of what's happening

Comment: `ls` is a "native" shell command. If you are implementing a shell, you should implement the commands as well, not just "delegate" them to the native shell.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen missclick, sorry

Comment: Seems like `tokens` should reset `i` to 0 before assigning the tokens to `array`, otherwise it just keeps growing and `exec` always uses `array[0]`.

Comment: Why is `i` a global variable?  Why is it never set back to 0?

Comment: Something to notice is that if `execvp` fails then the child process returns from `exec` and goes to the main loop, which will be very weird and confusing!

Comment: @EugeneSh. No, that is completely incorrect. ls is a program like any other. You might be thinking of cd.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: `ls` is not a native command in csh, bash, or zsh.

Comment: @user253751, Eric, ok, my bad. But I still think the OP is asked to actually implement it (as it is "mandatory" as the OP states).

Comment: @EugeneSh. I doubt it. Writing an actual shell that runs actual programs is a pretty common exercise.

Comment: @EugeneSh. actually it's a college "homework"

Comment: @AderbalNevesCalmetoJúnior I understand that. My understanding, is that you have a bunch of "mandatory" commands that are not supposed to depend on certain executable to be present or not on your system (such as `ls` which is common on *nix systems, but not on windows) - these should be implemented by yourself as "built-in" commands and not as external process. I might be wrong, of course, but in that case your "shell" could be a quite pointless input-`system()` loop.

Comment: @EugeneSh. It's supposed to work on Linux built-it

Comment: In `exec` you pass a pointer `a` to `waitpid` but you need to change it to `int a; waitpid(-1, &a, 0);`

Comment: If you press ctrl-d your program goes into an infinite loop printing out the last output over and over. You fix that by checking the return value you get from `getline()` with `if(getline(&entrada, &linha_tam, stdin) == -1) return 0;`.  Maybe write a quit function and call that both here and when processing the "q" command instead of "return 0;" in two places.

Comment: If you only check the first letter on your commands, then you can use               `array[0][0] == 'q'` instead of `strcmp()`.  This would also allow you to use a  `switch array[0][0] ...` so you repeat yourself less.

Comment: In general you will find that eliminating global variables makes your life easier.  Move the declaration of `entrada` and `linha_tam`  to `main()`.  Same with `array` but then 6you also need to pass it as an argument to `tokens)()` and `exec()`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of issues (per comments) but the easiest solution for the question asked is to change the variable `i` from global to a (loop) local scope in `tokens()`.  This also also eliminates the global `token` variable.  Unrelated but I also added bounds check for `array`:

```
void tokens(char *ent) {
    for(int i = 0; i < ARRAYMAX; i++) {
        array[i] = strtok(i ? NULL : ent, "\n ");
        if(!array[i]) break;
    }
    array[ARRAYMAX - 1] = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the global `i` variable to the local function `tokens`. As you never reset it to 0, you add more and more entries in `array`.

```
void tokens(void *ent){
    int i = 0;   
    token = strtok(ent, "\n ");       
    while(token != NULL){
        array[i++] = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, "\n ");
    }
    array[i] = NULL;
}
```